# Nhibernate passing in Castle.Proxies.UserProxy for positional parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate, parameters

I know I'm loosing my mind. I've done something and now when my app is accessing the db I get an error "could not execute query ... blah blah blah"

An inner message says "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

When I look at the sql that is in the exception it says blah blah blah `@p0` blah `@p1` and so on.  `@p1` to `@p3` are defined as I expect them to be but `@p0` is defined as `Castle.Proxies.UserProxy`.  Ok so if I put the sql in ssms query and sub the properties for `@p1` to `@p3` and then sub the property I expect for `@p0` then it returns instantly.

So let me see if I can be succinct.

1. My error says can't execute sql and also sql timed out.
2. My error message has the SQL.
3. The SQL has 4 parameters `@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3`.
4. The error shows the parameters as defined as

   ```
   \r\nPositional parameters:  #0>Castle.Proxies.UserProxy #1>2 #2>2 #3>/MenuItem/Calendar #4>/MenuItem\r\n
   ```
5. If I copy the sql into ssms query and substitute 1 ( the value I
   expected ), 2, 2, '/MenuItem/Calendar', 'MenuItem' then the sql
   returns right away.

What in tarnation is going on.

Help please

Raif

---

EDIT

---

Christ have mercy, I found the error, I have an onRequestEnd (or something) in the global.asax.  In that eventhandler I had commented out the close transaction.  On login I was updating the user.lastlogindate and then on the next page trying to load that same user.  I presume because of the transaction not being closed it was locking.  Furthermore, because I don't push the global.asax on deploys that explains why it was working in prod and not locally.

---

hell that doesnt make any sense about prod cuz it's compiled. whatever. forget about it

---

Sorry for existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding timeouts on simple queries (especially since you say it's returning instantly when you run the SQL itself) it would either be that the database server is not responding, or some issue with transactions and locking. Are you using TransactionScope?

As for the parameter, this might just be a case of showing the value before the proxy's identity have been extracted.

You would have to show what you're doing to get a more precise reply.